# Can a usb 3 port come in black color?

Tags: usb, version, lsusb

I have some doubts about one of my (new) laptop's usb ports regarding whether it is usb 2 or 3.

The port color is black, while it is reported that usb 3 come in blue. 
From ubuntu 14, I checked with `lsusb` and I got

```
bcdUSB               3.00
```

which should mean that the usb port is version 3. Does the black color mean something?

Comment: My ASUS ROG laptop has black-colored USB 3.0 ports.  Since USB 3.0 is so common these days and some machines exclusively only have USB 3.0 ports, the blue color is not always used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this isn't really a coding question, here's what a quick search results in:

> Manufacturers are recommended to distinguish USB 3.0 connectors from their USB 2.0 counterparts by blue color-coding of the Standard-A receptacles and plugs,[2] and by the initials SS.
>
> [...]
>
> Since USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports may coexist on the same machine and they look similar, USB 3.0 specification mandates appropriate color-coding and recommends that the Standard-A USB 3.0 connector has a blue insert (Pantone 300C color). The same color-coding applies to the USB 3.0 Standard-A plug.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0)

This **does not** necessarily mean that it is a USB2.0 port. It is most likely just of wrong color. You could try running a speed test (if you have a USB3.0 device to do so with).

Comment: Black is becoming more common, especially on laptops.  A lot of the USB ports will have the "SS" Super Speed logo near the port.  Also, if you look in the port with a flashlight, there would be four conductors like USB 2, plus another 5 conductors near the front of the jack for USB 3.  To check USB *devices* the extra 5 conductors would be in the rear of the connector instead of the front.